# "XML Parsing Error" in chat

Tags: bug, chat, firefox

This bug is specifically related to Firefox. [This cannot be reproduced in Chrome, Edge, or Internet Explorer 11](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/721/conversation/xml-parsing-error-reproduction).

When mentioned in chat, sending a message, or pressing the circle with the ping count in it shows an error in the console:

```
ML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/messages/ack
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

And the same in Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange chat, just with different URLs (`meta.stackexchange` is replaced with the site-specific URL). And, as I mentioned in the start, this has only been reproduced in Firefox. It seems to be fairly harmless though, since the URL it directs to shows a 404.

Comment: First thing I'd try is disabling all browser extension/addons. If this solve the problem, enable them one by one until you find which cause this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard all browser plugins disabled; still same issue

Answer (score 7):

### What is Happening

The response to POST `/messages/ack` has an empty body.

```
Content-Length: 0
```

It also doesn't specify any `Content-Type` header. You can see https://no-response-body.glitch.me for a similar response. In a normal request, browsers may default to treating a typeless response body as plain text. However, the `XMLHTTPRequest` specification's request handling section declares that *"if `mimeType` is the empty byte sequence, then set `mimeType` to `"text/xml"`"*.

You can see https://no-response-body.glitch.me/xml to compare how browsers handle the empty `text/xml` case: Firefox logs and displays an error, while Chrome seems to treat it like a valid empty document, even though it isn't. (At https://no-response-body.glitch.me/xml/invalid-body, you can see that Chrome does display an error for invalid non-empty XML bodies, but it still doesn't log anything in the console.) That explains what's happening here.

### What to Do

Per the spec, it is appropriate for browsers to be interpreting the response as `text/xml`, so the empty document is invalid and Firefox's warning is appropriate. Sending a `204 No Content` response instead of `200 OK` might be semantically better, but at https://no-response-body.glitch.me/204/xml we can see that Firefox still seems to treat this as an error.

The best choice may be to add a `Content-Type: text/plain` header to the response.

Comment: All of the above links show console errors in Edge and IE11.